# Console.Writeline -- Why output is missing

Tags: c#

Absolute newbie to C#. Was trying to run this program and the output simply would not show any computations.Why? I did not want to go through p,q,r,s for add, sub, multiply, divide etc., Also, how can i put space between "Please enter a number"  and userName?

```
string userName;
double  x, y;

Console.WriteLine(" Enter Your Name ");
userName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter A Number "+ userName);
First = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Another Number"+ userName);
Second = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("The addition of Two Numbers is",x,y, x*y);
Console.WriteLine("The substraction of Two Numbers is",x,y,x/y);
Console.WriteLine("The multiplication of Two Numbers is",x,y,x * y);
Console.WriteLine("The division of Two Numbers given is", x,y,x / y);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(" {0} + {1} = {2}",x,y, x*y);`

Comment: Look at this overload of the [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you pass additional parameters to show output, you must tell `WriteLine` *where* to put it by adding placeholders to the format line, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The product of Two Numbers {0} and {1} is {2}", x, y, x*y);
```

Positions are zero-based. The printed value of the first additional parameter (i.e. `x`) will replace `{0}`; the value of `y` will replace `{1}`, and the value of `x*y` will replace `{2}` in the final output.

The reason you did not have to do it with `userName` is that you passed a single parameter:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Another Number " + userName);
```

The result of appending `userName` to `"Please Enter Another Number"` string is passed as a single parameter to `WriteLine`. You could rewrite it with a format specifier, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Another Number {0}", userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with dasblinkenlight. Additionally, you may meet this line of code

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", "Hello", 53);
```

Result in this line being written: Hello, 53. {0} is the placeholder for the first argument after the format string, {1} is the second, and so on. This is called composite formatting in .NET - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx